Minimizing the total of the tails of the Fourier transform of a function of compact support
Let $\varphi:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}$ be an even, absolutely continuous function such that $\varphi'$ is of bounded total variation. Assume that $\varphi(1)=1$ and that $\varphi$ is supported on $[-1,1]$.
We would like to find $\varphi$ such that
$$I(\varphi) = \int_0^\infty \left|\int_t^\infty \widehat{\varphi}(u) du\right| dt$$
is minimal, where $\widehat{\varphi}$ is the Fourier transform of $\varphi$.
As you may gather from my questions of the last two weeks, the special case of $\varphi$ of the form $f\ast f$ is hard enough to be interesting and easy enough that (with the help of folks here and friends elsewhere) I am close to done finding the optimal $f$ (or at least determining the optimal $I(f\ast f)$).
However, it is also clear now that one can do better for general $\varphi$. For instance, for $\varphi = \cos(\pi t)|_{[-1,1]}$, $I(\varphi)$ is around $0.127$, which is substantially smaller than the minimal $I(f\ast f)$. Of course, for $\varphi$ not of the form $f\ast f$, the Fourier transform $\widehat{\varphi}(u)$ will not be non-negative, and the integral $\int_t^\infty \widehat{\varphi}(u) du$ will not generally be non-negative either. The problem then becomes harder, as the absolute value makes matters more difficult.

Is this a known problem? Of course it falls within the "uncertainty principle" class of questions.
Are there any known strategies to address this sort of problem? Here $\varphi = \cos(\pi t)|_{[-1,1]}$ is just an educated guess: it feels 'eigenfunctiony', and it gives a lower $I(\varphi)$ than a handful of other functions $\varphi$ I have tried, besides being better than the optimal $\varphi$ of the form $f\ast f$ (note that $f = \sqrt{2} \cos(\pi t)|_{[-1/2,1/2]}$ turned out not to be the optimal $f$ for that). Update: it seems $\varphi = (1-x^2)|_{[-1,1]}$ may actually be slightly better than $\varphi = \cos(\pi x)|_{[-1,1]}$, though one will need rigorous numerical integration to be sure.


If one tries a variational approach, it seems it is only the zeros of $\int_t^\infty \widehat{\varphi}(u) du$ that matter. Are those enough to determine $\varphi$?

The variational approach seems to imply the following: a function $\varphi$ can be optimal only if, for every odd function f supported on [-1,1], the Fourier transform of $f$ is orthogonal to $\sgn(\varphi(x)) u(x)$, where $u(x)$ is the Heaviside function. Not sure what to do with this. We would be done if we had a function $\varphi$ such that the (inverse) Fourier transform of  $\sgn(\varphi(x)) u(x)$ is supported on $\mathbb{R}\setminus [-1,1]$. Is that a fantasy?
